# Using pagination with query string for a search form which has the method set to get in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, get, pagination

I'm banging my head on the keyboard trying to figure out a way to use query string with pagination every thing works fine until `FIRST` page link appears.

All other links have the query string appended to their end but the `First` page link `misses the query string`

Links for other pages:

```
http://localhost/index.php/search/index/9?q=some_Data_From_Form
```

The FIRST page link show the link that I've set in the `$config['base_url']`
variable:

```
http://localhost/index.php/search/index/
```

The search form:

```
$attributes=array('id'=>'search','class'=>'clearfix','method'=>'get');
echo form_open(base_url().'index.php/search/index',$attributes);
```

It has a textbox with the name set to `q`.

I stumbled upon a few answers/examples on stackoverflow and this is what I wrote:

The Pagination configuration file has

```
$config['per_page'] = '1';
$config['uri_segment'] = '3';
```

and others like `num_tag_open` etc.

The controller class:

```
class Search extends CI_Controller {
    public function Search(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('input');
        $this->load->model('blog_model');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->config->load('pagination'); //other pagination related config variables
    }

    public function index($page=0){
        $q = trim($this->input->get('q'));
        if(strlen($q)>0){
            //validate input and show data
            $config['enable_query_strings']=TRUE;
            $getData = array('q'=>$q);
            $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/index.php/search/index/';   
            $config['suffix'] = '?'.http_build_query($getData,'',"&amp;");

            $data['rows'] = $this->blog_model->getBySearch($q,$this->config->item('per_page'),$page);
            if(empty($data['rows'])){
                //no results found              

            }else{
                //match found
                $config['total_rows'] = $this->blog_model->getBySearchCount($q);
                $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
                $link->linkBar = $this->pagination->create_links();
                $this->load->view('myview',array($data,$link));
            }
        }else if(strlen($q)==0){
            //warn user for the missing query and show a searchbox

        }
    }
}
```

S.O.S! Guys, please help me out

Comment: +1 for your head & keyboard :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't believe this, I spent hours searching the web for a solution !
It was always with me.I should have opened the pagination library and viewed its content before I posted this question.Just one line and problem solved.
I added the following line in the index method.
`$config['first_url'] = '/index.php/search/index/?q='.$q;`

Comment: Thank you for your post really useful.