# Codeigniter paginate search results using get method

Tags: php, codeigniter, get, pagination

I have a codeigniter search form which includes a dropdown list (Car) and a checkbox array (Car types). I was using POST method to get values from database but post method conflicts with pagination so I decided to use GET method. But now my 'if' statement does not work and it returns me 'else' scenario (i.e. 'search_nok' page with a message "Please select your search options"). Could you please check my code and help me to find the mistake.

Here is my controller

```
   public function search($offset = 0) {
                $limit = 5;

                $this->load->library('form_validation');
                $this->load->model('model_x');

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('car', 'Car','required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('types', 'Car Type','required');

               if($this->form_validation->run()) {

        $car= $this->input->get('car');
        $types = $this->input->get('types'); 

        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/abc/cont/search/'; 

        // 'http://localhost/abc' is my base url

        $config['total_rows'] = 14;
        $config['per_page'] = 5; 

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->initialize($config);

                if ($this->model_x->did_search($car, $types, $limit, $offset)){

                $data["results"] = $this->model_x->did_search($car, $types, $limit, $offset); 
                $this->load->view("search_ok",$data);           
                }          
                }
                else
                {
                $data['message'] = 'Please select your options.';   

                $this->load->view("search_nok",$data);          
                 }              
           }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter Validation: possible to validate GET query strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883949/codeigniter-validation-possible-to-validate-get-query-strings)

Comment: no it's a different question

Comment: Same question. You are trying to validate a form, received through `$_GET`. There are like at least 3 equal questions on SO.

Comment: no I am trying to display my search results using codeigniter pagination. It does not matter if I use get or post, but when I try to validate the results, it does not work for the second page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the validation class in `CodeIgniter` does not check for `$_GET` parameters and tries to validate the `POST` fields and finds no `car` or `types`.

To complement this with a quick fix to validate the `$_GET` parameters you are sending (and since you have no POST) you could set the `POST` array to be the same as `GET` therefore passing the parameters to the validation class.

```
$_POST = $_GET;
```

this should be before the validation is run:

```
$_POST = $_GET;
$this->form_validation->set_rules('car', 'Car','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('types', 'Car Type','required');

if($this->form_validation->run()) {
    // ....
}
```

**UPDATE**

To keep the [search parameters across pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080093/using-pagination-with-query-string-for-a-search-form-which-has-the-method-set-to?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. I just added the $_POST = $_GET; and now the code works exactly as in the past i.e. it displays the first page correctly but when I click on the second page, search options are disappearing from the url and I get 'else' statement

Comment: That means that in your view your link does not include the offset or page you are currently on so it can calculate the "next" page when the controller is called again. It's either that, or if your view has that, than the problem is in your `$this->model_x->did_search` not sending the right `$data` to the view

Comment: when first loading the results the url is: **http://localhost/abc/cont/search?country=Mazda&types%5B%5D=sedan&filterSearch=Search** When trying to load the second page, the url is **http://localhost/abc/cont/search/5** I wonder why car and types are not included in the url for next page

Comment: Giving `$_GET`'s values to `$_POST` is breaking what they were designed for. But it seems, that for some reason, this solution has been suggestion in previous occasions... which is bad as well.

Comment: It's a "known" fix for Codeigniter's validation class to validate `GET` parameters, and as long you are in pages where there are no `POST` to override, this should be fine.

Comment: still cannot keep search parameters across pages